# How can I check if a cell in Excel contains a number over a specific value?

Tags: excel, function, cell

Before I start: Please don't use VBA in your answers, the project I am working on does not allow this.

I would like to see if a cell contains a number larger than a specific integer, for example 10.

"A1, A2, A3, A4, A5" will be allowed while

"A7, A8, A9, A10, A11" will not be allowed.
Is there any way I can manage this using Excel functions **without** VBA?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1>10,"allowed","not allowed")
```

and copy down.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If the cells *contain* text in which a number is *embedded*, then use this *Array Formula*:

```
=IF(--MID(SUMPRODUCT(--MID("01"&A7,SMALL((ROW($1:$300)-1)*ISNUMBER(-MID("01"&A7,ROW($1:$300),1)),ROW($1:$300))+1,1),10^(300-ROW($1:$300))),2,300)>10,"allowed","not allowed")
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know about that. I need to check if the cell CONTAINS a number over ten, not if it is over ten itself.

Comment: @Dovahkiin  Now I understand.

Comment: @Dovahkiin  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: oh hell, you did it! Thanks a lot mate, I was looking for this so long!

Comment: I thought the question was to check the string "A7, A8, A9, A10, A11" for a number greater than 10 and then return "not allowed".  I found a solution for that problem for Google Sheets =if(Max(SPLIT(A2,CONCATENATE(SPLIT(A2,".0123456789"))))>10,"NOT ALLOWED","ALLOWED") but didn't manage an excel formula.

Comment: @Gordon You may be correct...I often do not interpret questions corretly.